# Automate input for new vector

Tags: r, vector

I was wondering if you had any idea what R code I could use to automate my process.

I would like to repeat "chunks" of an initial vector (Vec1). I divide the vector in groups of 4 values and repeat each group 5 times. Currently, with my bad technique, each time I add a new experiment to the analysis I have to manually create a vector to indicate which chunk I would like to repeat next. In the end I put the vector corresponding to each experiment together to get my desired output.

```
Vec1 <- A simple numeric vector that grows in size for each new experiment. Each new experiment extends the vector by 4 additional values.

Exp1 <- rep(Vec1 [1:4], times=5)
Exp2 <- rep(Vec1 [5:8], times=5)
Exp3 <- rep(Vec1 [9:12], times=5)


NewVector<- c(Exp1, Exp2, Exp3)
```

Could I use a trick to automate it?

Many thanks for the help,

Best regards,

Edouard M.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about "automate". You could write a function that takes the values 1:4 and adds multiples of 4 to it.

```
add_exp <- function(values = 1:4, n = 0) {
  rep(values, 5) + 4 * n
}
```

Then `add_exp()` gives:

```
 [1] 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
```

And `add_exp(n = 1)` gives:

```
 [1] 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8
```

So you could get `NewVector` using:

```
NewVector<- c(add_exp(), add_exp(n = 1), add_exp(n = 2))
```

Or if you wanted to use `lapply` to supply the values of `n`:

```
NewVector <- unlist(lapply(0:2, function(x) add_exp(n = x)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. The add_exp and lapply functions you shared work wonders. I just have to supply the number of experiments I am working with. Just like the solution presented by jblood94, NewVector is now a vector with the positions of the desired values in my initial Vec1 vector. Do you see an elegant way to tell lapply to look in Vec1 for its output values?
Thanks a lot for your great help.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sequence`:

```
n <- 3L # number of experiments
v <- 4L # length of vector added for each experiment
r <- 5L # number of replications

sequence(rep(v, n*r), rep(seq(1, n*v, v), each = r))
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  1  2  3  4  1  2  3  4  1  2  3  4  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  5
#> [26]  6  7  8  5  6  7  8  5  6  7  8  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  9 10 11 12  9 10
#> [51] 11 12  9 10 11 12  9 10 11 12
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. So this code indicates what location on Vec1 I should use to create my new vector. But I still need to ask R to match this new sequence with Vec1 right? Or am I missing something? And I am not sure I know how to do that.

Comment: I guess I answered my own question.
I just did;
seq <- sequence(rep(v, n*r), rep(seq(1, n*v, v), each = r))
Newvector <- Vec1[seq]
Newvector

Comment: That's correct. Or just `Newvector <- Vec1[sequence(rep(v, n*r), rep(seq(1, n*v, v), each = r))]`. Maybe not a good idea to assign `seq` to a variable, since it is a base R function.